# How to run xmlread function in Octave?

Tags: java, xml, octave, xerces

When I run xmlread function in Octave, I get

```
>> xmlread()
warning: the 'xmlread' function is not yet implemented in Octave

Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
error: 'xmlread' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

I have [found a documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/function/xmlread.html), saying it is in `io` package of Octave-Forge. Unfortunately, just installing this package didn't help. It is said to set paths to `xerces`, but unfortunately I can't find `xml-apis.jar` of `2.11` version. I found [only `xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0), but adding of it alone didn't help. Adding it with [ancient `xml-apis-2.0.2.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2) didn't help:

```
>> javaaddpath(fullfile('lib','xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar'));
>> javaaddpath(fullfile('lib','xml-apis-2.0.2.jar'));
>> xmlread();
warning: the 'xmlread' function is not yet implemented in Octave

Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
error: 'xmlread' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

How to succeed?

Comment: have you `pkg load io` before running xmlread?

Comment: no; why would i?

Comment: because the manual says you have to?

Comment: Can you point me to there please?

Comment: Have you tried to run `pkg load io; xmlread()..` in the meanwhile?

Comment: Not yet, I am in different area :)